# How to dockerize springboot app with Neo4j

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, neo4j

I am trying to dockerize my springboot application with my Neo4j application.
This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  myneo4j:
    image: neo4j:5.15.0
    container_name: "myneo4j"
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/12345678
    volumes:
      - ./db/data:/data
      - ./db/conf:/conf
      - ./db/logs:/logs
      - ./db/plugins:/plugins
  springboot-neo4j:
    image: springboot-neo4j:1.0
    container_name: springboot-neo4j
    depends_on:
      - myneo4j
    ports:
      - 3002:3002
    links:
      - myneo4j
```

This is my application.properties:

```
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://host.docker.internal:7687
spring.neo4j.authentication.username=neo4j
spring.neo4j.authentication.password=12345678
```

I already looked up past forums and the spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://host.docker.internal:7687 was the fix for most people except it doesn't work for me here.

myneo4j container works and runs. the springboot-neo4j container doesn't work. It gives me this error:

```
springboot-neo4j  | Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Unable to connect to localhost:7687, ensure the database is running and that there is a working network connection to it.
```

https://github.com/phammings/Music-Microservice-API
Here is my github if anyone would like to replicate my error. I am trying to dockerize my profile-microservice with absolute no luck

Thank you so much if anyone can let me know whats the fix here

Comment: `host.docker.internal` seems wrong (imagine trying to connect to your home network's router, when you're trying to reach a process on the same machine you're on locally); also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.  In Spring Boot 3.2.1, [the property is named `spring.neo4j.uri`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html#data.nosql.neo4j.connecting) without `.data.`; does changing this help?

Comment: I still get ```springboot-neo4j  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused``` even when I removed ```.data.``` and used the uri: ```bolt://localhost:7687```

Comment: `localhost` ("the current container") isn't right either.  You should be able to use the Compose service name `myneo4j` as a host name.  This is specific to this Compose setup, so consider setting a `SPRING_NEO4J_URI` environment variable instead of compiling it into the application.

Comment: My application properties I changed to ```spring.data.neo4j.uri=${SPRING_DATA_NEO4J_URI}``` and my docker-compose.yml I amde sure to include ```    environment:
      - SPRING_DATA_NEO4J_URI=bolt://myneo4j:7687```
I still get the same Connection refusal error. Am I allowed to post my github here perhaps for someone to git clone and replicate my error?

Comment: even ```spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://myneo4j:7687``` does not work

Comment: I've removed ```image: springboot-neo4j:1.0 container_name: springboot-neo4j``` from sprintboot-neo4j and Now I dont see my ConnectionError anymore however, I cannot send any requests via port 3002.

Answer (score -1):

verify that the two containers (services) are in the same network.

And you need to specify that you want to start the Second container when the first one  have finish.

Comment: I believe they are in the same network since they are both in the docker-compose.yml unless I am wrong. I have heard skme

Comment: ```NETWORK ID     NAME                  DRIVER    SCOPE


228308eac5c2   bridge                bridge    local



199db476dd3f   host                  host      local


4105a814e6da   none                  null      local


a9a2edb89590   resources_default     bridge    local


57c2371aaf2a   resources_mynetwork   bridge    local```
I see they are on the same local network here? I start my neo4j before my springboot which i see in the console so there should be no race condition error there some people online say

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).